# Calculate the credible interval for posterior distribution ~ N(69.07,0.53^2)

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I'm not really sure as to how to calculate the credible interval for this posterior distribution I'm given

~ N(69.07, 0.53^2)

And I need to find the probability of the interval, of length 1, which has the highest probability.

I know this interval is about to average ie 69.07+-0.5 but I don't know how to calculate the probability of this interval

Answer (score 1):

Your posterior distribution is $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 69.07, \sigma=0.53).$
Finding the interval $(L_{ci}, U_{ci})$ of length $U_{ci}-L_{ci} = 1$ that contains
the greatest probability under the posterior PDF requires some sort of
computation.

As you say, intuitively this interval will be about $69.07 \pm 0.5$ because
that is were the density function is highest.

Not knowing the kinds of computations with which you are familiar, I will
do a 'grid search' in R statistical software to illustrate the idea. This
is a brute-force method that looks at all 'reasonable' intervals of length $1$
(30,001 intervals with
endpoints rounded to four places), finds the probability of each, and
picks the one with the largest probability. It confirms that the interval
$(68.57, 69.57)$ is indeed the correct one. It has about probability
about 65.5%. [One can prove that this is the shortest 65.5% posterior credible interval.]

Here is some R code:

```
 L = seq(67,70, by = 0.0001);  U = L+1
 pr = pnorm(L+1, 69.07, .53) - pnorm(L, 69.07, .53)
 L.ci = L[pr == max(pr)]  # lower end of interval (length 1) with largest probability
 U.ci = L.ci+1;  L.ci;  U.ci;  max(pr)
 ## 68.57
 ## 69.57
 ## 0.6545217

 curve(dnorm(x, 69.07, .53), 67, 71, lwd=2,  ylab="PDF", main="Posterior Distribution")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2"); abline(v=c(L.ci,U.ci), col="blue")
 abline(h = dnorm(L.ci, 69.07, .53), col="red")
```

The figure below (made with the last three lines of code) shows the
interval boundaries, and illustrates that the the interval 'uses' the
largest values of the posterior density.

[image]

*Note:* It is common to use 'probability symmetric' intervals--especially
with symmetrical (or nearly-symmetric) posterior distributions. Below is
R code to find a 95% credible interval $(68.03, 70.11)$ that cuts probability 2.5% from each tail of the
posterior distribution.

```
 qnorm(c(.025,.975), 69.07, .53)
 ## 68.03122 70.10878
```

Comment: Oh right, I was just wondering if there was a way to calculate this using the normal tables?

Comment: Knowing you need values near 69.07, you can go $\pm 0.5$ from there to get an interval of length $1.$ And you could use normal tables to find the probability. Then you need to argue that no other interval of length $1$ has greater probability. // If you give up distance $\epsilon$ on the left, why do you need to go out $> \epsilon$  on the right to re-capture the probability lost on the left? Etc. Don't know the background or level of your course, so I can't really speculate exactly what is expected of you.

Comment: Do you know how to use printed normal tables to find $P(68.57 < X \le 69.57)$ for $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 69.07,\, \sigma = 0.53)?$

Comment: see that's what I tried to do but I seemed to be getting the wrong answer each time

Comment: Standardize to use printed normal tables: By symmetry, prob is $2P(68.07<X\le 68.67) = 2P\left(\frac{68.07-68.07}{.53}<\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le\frac{68.57-68.07}{.63} =.9493\right)$$\approx 2P(0 < Z \le .95) = 2(.3289).$ Done quickly; please check for typos.

Comment: Ah right. Cheers, I'll definitely have another look at this